# How to use webrtc insde google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I have developped a google chrome extension.

I am trying now to integrate webRTC feature inside:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
console.log("step1");
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream){
    console.log("step2");
    $('#myVideo').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    window.localStream = stream;
    console.log("step3");

  }, function(error){ 
    console.log(error);
 });
```

I got an error:

```
step1
NavigatorUserMediaError {constraintName: "", message: "", name: "InvalidStateError"}
```

Any idea ?

Do I need any special permission to use webrtc inside my extension ? and is it possible to access webrtc in a extension ?

regards

Here is the screenshot of what I call the "popup" (extension = popup + background)
[image: Pop up window = chrome extension]

Comment: How do you current permissions look like? It needs "videoCapture" [according to this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions). But the doc is for apps, perhaps they differ from extensions.

Comment: video capture and audio capture are ONLY for applications, not extensions: I have ALREADY tested that !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use WebRTC or the speech recognition API in the background page of a Chrome extension, you need to open a page from your extension in a tab, (popup) window or iframe (within a tab) (if you use an iframe, don't forget to list the page in [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)). In this page, invoke `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` to trigger the permission prompt. After the user approves the permission, your extension (in particular the background page) can request access to the microphone / camera again, and the request will automatically be approved.

Whether silent approval after a one-time prompt is desirable [is debated](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453150), and this is also the reason that [`audioCapture` and `videoCapture` permissions cannot be used in extensions yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160337#c35). The `audioCapture` and `videoCapture` permissions *will* become available in the future though, so I recommend putting these permissions in your manifest file if your extension needs it, even when the current versions of Chrome do not recognize the permission for extensions.

Comment: Hi: I did that: the popup invokes navigator.webkitGetUserMedia and .. This does not help.
I tried both: in popup and in background with no success.

Comment: @yarek Not the [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) / [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) popup, but a popup **window**. Like one that's created using `window.open` / `chrome.tabs.create` / `chrome.windows.create`.

Comment: You mean a popup outside the plugin ? Not inside the plugin itself ? I success did it inside the options page. But is there a mean to do that inside the plugin popup inside ?

Comment: @yarek If by "popup", you mean one of the popups I referred to in my previous comment, then not directly. You can use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to insert an iframe containing your a page from your extension (`yourframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('page.html');`) in the current tab that requests the access in order to see a permission request.

Comment: I edited the question and have included a screenshot of what I call the popup (the content of the extension)

Comment: @yarek That's exactly what I was referring to (that's a browser action popup). Use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` as I said, or `chrome.tabs.create` if you cannot execute a script in the current tab.

Comment: ok sorry I still don't understand (probably because I am french): 
So If I understand well, I cannot ask the authorization to webcam from the browser action popup, but I need to open a new tab (like the options tabs) and then I can grant the access to webcam: Am I right ?

Comment: @yarek Yes, or insert a frame that requests access to the web cam/mic. You only need to do this once, after that, any requests from your popup or background page will automatically be approved.

Comment: by inserting a frame, you mean: I can insert a frame INSIDE the browser action popup ? That would be great ! If yes, this frame source must be external (http://) or local (included within the extension) ?

Comment: @yarek No, inside the current tab. The crucial parts of this idea are 1) the getUserMedia request has to originate from a (sub)frame within a tab (otherwise the permission bar/bubble won't appear) and 2) the permission request needs to be triggered from your chrome-`extension://[extensionid]` URL (because permissions are stored per origin).