# How to read voice input in a chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

So I need to use the `webkitSpeechRecognition()` api to read voice input from the user and then fill a `text area` with whatever value is returned for `webSpeechRecognition`. Now the problem is when I do that from a `popup page` in chrome extension, it does not asks for microphone access. How can I solve it ? I have read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183128/5143144 but I am unable to make anything of it. Another issue is, even if I am able to get microphone access, is it possible to use it to do `webkitSpeechRecognition` in the popup of the chrome extension.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after searching a lot and getting a reference from one of the stack overflow answers and chrome forums. Just leaving this here in case you find it useful.

So all you have to do is `ask for the permissions on a different page which has the extension url`. Once a user allows permission to microphone there, your browser extension will be able to access microphone.